# Errors compiling c++ ofx plugins

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ofx

I am a new to programming and had no previous experience in any programming language.

I am trying to compile a bunch of open source ofx plugins i found on github and use them in davinci resolve. Here is the link to the plugins: https://github.com/devernay/openfx-misc

I am trying to compile them in visual studio 2015, like it says in the installation guide for windows, however when i open the visual studio solution and try to build the code i get a lot of errors. Sometimes 200-300 in each plugin code.

I'm not too sure what to do with this, and whether it's a visual studio incopatibility issue (it did say that the solution was written in VS2010 rather than 2015) or there are actual errors in the code.

Here is a screenshot of the error page:[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaEhl.jpg)

Comment: If you have no experience in programming, why are you even trying to build some GitHub project? If you really want to use these plugins, you'd better learn the very basics of C++ first. Compiling tools without knowing what's actually going on isn't a good idea.

Comment: You're going to hit more than one issue doing this download and compile. There will be loads and loads of issues. C++ is also one of the harder languages to get to compile, so having zero programming experience it's really a bit of a deep end to jump into. I suggest you find someone who's done it before.

Comment: Can you compile a simple hello world program like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/program_structure/)?

Comment: Well I don't really want to be doing this. I do colour grading and I need the plugins to do exactly that, use them for colour grading in davinci resolve. This is the only set of plugins that allows to have the histogram equalizer in davinci resolve. There isn't a compiled version of this on the net, so I guess I have to compile them. Don't get me wrong, I don't like to ask stupid questions, and there are plenty of people on colourgrading forums doing that and it's lame, but I don't know programing and I need these damn plugins, so any help with this is much appreciated.